# Mathway.com can get to my iOS camera

Tags: iphone, ios, keyboard, camera

Mathway.com has a keyboard on their site that looks like this when loaded into iOS safari.

[image: safari page]

When you click on the camera icon, it loads the phones camera ready to take a picture. I would have expected it to ask me, or since Safari is set to “deny” access to the camera, it to just not work.

But it does, and with no asking of any kind.

At first, I thought it was a custom keyboard, but if I tap in the white space and drag up the keyboard goes too. (Not normal for iOS keyboards, but fairly normal for a webpage).

Also, I did not install or give any permissions for a custom keyboard for that site.

So it seems this “keyboard” is just part of the site.

So how is it getting access to the camera so easily?

Comment: a photo selector is different from permissions that allow a site to record what's happening real time and store it. Just like a file selector doesn't allow a site to upload all the files even though you see a native file selector layover listing all the files. Also if you have access to a mac, you can also go through the source code